# Turning my desktop webpage into responsive design to fit for ipad + mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i have created a webpage initially for laptop view, and i try to use media queries to adjust the css styling and make it fit on ipad and mobile, as i set the width of the (.content) element to 100%, the content doesnt actually become 100%, there is a relatively big margin. i also want to say that i used position relative to adjust the position of the form, and paragraph elements in my initial laptop view, could it affect my media query ?
anyhelp would be appreciated, i have to submit this assignment tomorrow :D thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doIOg.png)

```css
body{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

.content {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgb(247, 246, 244);
    padding: 10px;
}



div.logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(147, 235, 238);
}

div.navi {
    
    background-color: rgb(228, 226, 217);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

p.nav {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(97, 87, 226);
}

img {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    
}

/* inner body styling */


div.inner-body {
    background-image: url(image/book2.png); 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
    
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    left:1000px;
    left: 338px;
    font-size: 30px;
    
}

.para {
    
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    left:345px;
    top:74px;
    background-color: rgb(206, 200, 180);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

form {
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: fit-content;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    left:350px;
    top:140px;
    background-color: rgb(240, 239, 228);
}

.navi2 {
    
    width: fit-content;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 600px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    top:300px;
}

.user-links {
    position: relative;
    left:20px;
    bottom:30px;
}

.user-links:link{
    color: brown;
}

.userlogo {
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 100px;
}


.btn {
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}







/* footer styling */

.emaillogo, .telelogo {
    width: 20px;
}
div.foot {
    
    background-color: brown;
}
footer{
    background-color: rgb(126, 226, 230);
    height: 200px;
}

.footimage {
    width: 400px;
    
    margin: 0;
}
div.contact{
    width: fit-content;
    height: 200px;
    
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    bottom: 185px;
    font-size: 12px;

}

.usefullinks {
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    left:750px;
    bottom:400px;

}

.connect {
    width: fit-content;
    position: relative;
    left: 1000px ;
    bottom: 524px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.fb, .tw, .yt, .ln {
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}

@media screen and (max-width:915px) {
    .content{
        width: 100%;
    }


    .inner-body {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width:415px) {
    .content{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .inner-body {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="log-it-reports.css">
    <script src="log-it-reports.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "content">
        <div class="logo">
        <img src="image/logo1.png" alt="Academy Logo" >
        </div>
        <div class="navi">
            <p id="nav"> 
                <a href="homepage.html" title=" Home Page"> Home</a> |
                <a href="academics.html" title=" Academics Page">Academics</a> |
                <a href="services.html" title=" Services">Services</a> |
                <a href="covid-19.html" title=" Covid-19 Page">Covid-19</a> | 
                <a href="students&parents.html" title=" Students&Parents Page">Students & Parents</a> |
                <a href="Transcripts.html" title="Transcripts Page">Transcripts</a>  |
                <a href="staff.html" title="Staff Page">Staff</a> |
                <a href="career.html" title="Career Available">Career</a> |
                <a href="events" title="Events Page">Events</a> | 
                <a href="studentaccount.html" title="Student Account">Student Account</a> |
                
        </p>
        </div>
    
       
       <div class="inner-body">
           <div class = "header" >
            <h1>Steps For IT-Issues Logging:</h1>
           </div>
       
       <div class="para">
           <p>Please read the following instructions before submitting a report:</p> 
           <ol>
               <li>Fill out all of the fields.</li>
               <li>Use a valid email.</li>
               <li>Select a problem type.</li>
               <li>Be as detailed as possible so that the IT staff could address the issue properly (100 characters minumum).</li>
               <li>Normally most issues get addressed within 2 hours, please be patient.</li>
           </ol>
       </div>
       <div class="form1">
        <form  method="GET" onsubmit=" return formValidations() " action="log-it-reports.html"><br>
          <div id= "errorMsg"></div>
          <div>
          <label for="subject"><b>Subject:</label> 
          <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject Title"  > 
          </div><br>
          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg2"></div>
          <div>
          <label for="email"><b>Email:</label> 
          <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="staff@wearview.com">  
          </div><br>
          
          <div>
            <select name="techtype" id="problemtypes">
                <option value="">Problem Type</option>
                <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                <option value="Software">Software</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
          </div>
          <div class="error" id= "errorMsg3"></div><br>
          
          <div>
          <textarea id="description" placeholder="Description goes here" name="descript" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea>
          </div>          
          
<div class="error" id= "errorMsg4"></div>
          
          <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
            <input type="checkbox" id="notify" name="notify" value="">
            <label for="notify">Inform me by email when issue is resolved.</label> 
        </div>
          
        </form>
       </div>
       <div class="navi2">
           <div class="userimage">
               <img class="userlogo" src="image/userlogo.png" alt="User Image">
           </div>
           <div class="user-links">
               <navi>
                <a class="staffname" href="staffname.html" title=" Staff Name">Staff Name</a> <br><br>
                <a href="inbox.html" title=" User Inbox">Inbox</a> <br><br>
                <a href="notifications.html" title="Notifications">Notifications</a> <br><br>
                <a href="files.html" title="Files">Files</a> <br><br>
                <a href="settings.html" title="Settings">Settings</a> <br><br>
                <a href="help.html" title="Help">Help</a>  <br><br>
                <a href="qr-for-mobile.html" title="QR for Mobile">QR For Mobile</a> <br><br>
                <a href="logout.html" title="Log Out">Log Out</a> 
               </navi>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
       <div class="foot">
           <footer id = "footy">
           <div>
            <img class="footimage" src="image/logo1.png" alt="Academy Logo"  width="400px">
           </div>
           <div class="contact">
               
               <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                <p><img class="emaillogo" src="image/email (2).png" alt="emaillogo"> :wearview_academy@wearview.com</p>
              <p><img class="telelogo" src="image/tele.png" alt="telelogo"> :+2499100000000</p>

           </div>
           <div class="usefullinks">
            <h3>Userful Links</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="career.html" title=" Jobs Available">Career</a></li> 
                <li><a href="websiteerror.html" title=" Report A Website Issue">Report A Website Issue</a></li> 
                <li><a href="aboutus.html" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="covid-19.html" title="Covid-19">Covid-19</a></li>
                <li><a href="events" title=" FAQs Page">Events</a></li>
                
            </ul>  
           </div>
           <div class="connect">
            <h3>Connect With Us </h3><br>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com" title= "facebook"><img class="fb" src="image/fb.png" alt = "Facebook" /></a>     
                <a href="https://www.twitter.com" title= "twitter"><img class="tw" src="image/tw.jpg" alt = "Twitter" /></a>      
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com" title= "youtube"><img class="yt" src="image/you.png" alt = "Youtube" /></a>      
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" title= "linkedin"><img class="ln" src="image/linkd.png" alt = "LinkedIn" /></a>      

           </div>
           </footer>
       </div>
       
        
    </div>

    


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your css to the following:

```css
@media (max-width:415px) {
    .content{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {  
        margin: 0;
    }
    .inner-body {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This will get rid of the space between the content and the screen border!

Comment: I used your media query and the result is the same, i have added a link to my screenshot of the result on ipad mini , take a look please.

Comment: I have only provided the query for mobile. Sorry, I missed the other one. You should be able to fix your problem by simply adding the same tags to your other media query!

Comment: i understand what you mean, i created another query for mobile using your query, but its the same result, i would like to ask: for media queries, do i have to recreate the entire CSS to make it fit for the specific device ?

Comment: You will have to change certain elements of your website to be smaller when you are making the website compatible for mobile, however, you don't necessarily have to change all your CSS.